# Why is that when I apply a margin to a child div tag, it affects the parent div tag is CSS?

Tags: css

I have the following code and I am wondering why is that when I apply `margin-top: 100px;` to the logo id it affects the wrapper div tag in that it also `inherits` a `margin-top` of 100px however if I apply a `padding-top` it works the way I intend it to work.

**CODE**

```
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />

    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="" />

    <style type="text/css" media="all">

        * {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }

        body {
            font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
            font-size: 1em;
            font-style: normal;
            font-color: normal;
            color: #ffffff;
        }


        #wrapper {
            background-color: #018eb9;
            width: 100%;
            height: 300px;
        }

        #innerwrapper {
            width: 600px;
            margin: 0px auto;
        }

        #logo {
            padding-top: 100px;
        }

        #menu  li {
            display: inline;
        }

    </style>

    <title>Sample</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="innerwrapper">
            <div id="logo">logo</div>
            <div id="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li>home</li>
                    <li>about</li>
                    <li>faq</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**EDIT**

As requested the markup that is `causing` the issue is

```
#logo {
 padding-top: 100px;
}
```

So if I change `padding-top` to `margin-top`, you'll notice the background color move down 100px

**Further Editing**

In light of the responses regarding vertical margin collapsing from everyone I found an excellent guide for beginners like myself at http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/css/margincollapsing

Comment: Could you include a sample of the markup that's causing the problem, as well as the CSS?

Comment: "markup" refers to HTML. CSS is not markup.

Comment: @BoltClock - Thanks. I wasn't aware of that. What is CSS referred to if not `markup`?

Comment: It's a stylesheet language. Sometimes I just refer to my CSS code as "styles" (or even "code").

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I am wondering why is that when I apply `margin-top: 100px;` to the
>   logo id it affects the wrapper div tag in that it also `inherits` a
>   `margin-top` of 100px

It sounds like you need to read up on collapsing margins.

- http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins
- http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins

One possible quick fix is to set `overflow: hidden` on `#innerwrapper`.

Comment: Wow, I didn't realize there as such a thing. Am reading about it as we speak. I am however confused as to why I would set the `overflow` to `hidden` on the `#innerwrapper` and not `#wrapper`?

Comment: I'm sure either way would work, actually, since `#logo` is contained within both.

Answer (score 3):

This is part of [collapsing margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins). It's a rendering phenomenon; nothing is actually being inherited.

These statements are of particular interest:

> Adjoining vertical margins collapse...

> Two margins are *adjoining* if and only if:
>
> - no line boxes, no clearance, no padding and no border separate them
> - both belong to vertically-adjacent box edges, i.e. form one of the following pairs:
>
>   - top margin of a box and top margin of its first in-flow child

In this case, the top margins of `#wrapper`, `#innerwrapper` and `#logo` are *all* affected by collapse.